# Eigen SparseLU factorize too slow

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, eigen

In my code, SparseLU.factorize() takes 1'20" to execute. How to speed it up? Or, are there any inappropriate steps slowing it down in my code?

Here is the code:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> F(verticesNum, verticesNum);  // verticesNum is about 34918
// reserve space for non-zero elements in sparse matrix
F.reserve(Eigen::VectorXi::Constant(verticesNum, 20));
// build matrix operator
for (int i = 0; i < vertices->size(); i++) 
{
    // ... some algorithm 
}

// build solver for matrix
Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<int>> solver; 

// tailor solver to matrix
solver.analyzePattern(F);
solver.factorize(F);
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You are compiling with full optimization? What's the split in computation time between `analyzePattern` and `factorize` ?

Comment: This question is nearly identical to one asked earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62386137/can-eigen-matrix-solver-use-multi-threads-and-how

Comment: @Botje yup I logged into wrong account earlier. Will delete the previous one

Comment: First of all, if (according to your other question), your matrix is a Laplacian (and thus symmetric) you could at least try a Cholesky-based solver. But overall, Eigen just provides rather basic Sparse solvers (sufficient for small/medium-sized or non-time critical problems). You could try one of the wrapper-libraries (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicSparseSystems.html -- which one fits best, really depends on your matrix structure -- and what license you can accept for your project).